# i want that when the give input in employee_address is Banglore and salary is more than 25000,i get all the details of employee

Tags: java, string, if-statement, boolean

I have written this code but when i am giving input Banglore and 26000 it is not returning desired condition.

I want to get all employee details when the employee address is Banglore and salary is more than 25000.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ContactManager {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);

        int employee_id;
        String employee_name;
        String address;
        int mobile;
        int salary;
        String q;

        System.out.println("empolyee_id:");
        employee_id=s.nextInt();

        System.out.println("employee_name:");
        employee_name=s.next();

        System.out.println("mobile:");
        mobile=s.nextInt();

        System.out.println("address:");
        address=s.next();

        System.out.println("salary:");
        salary=s.nextInt();

        q = "Banglore";

        if(address==q && salary > 25000) {
            System.out.println(employee_name);
            System.out.println(employee_id);
            System.out.println(address);
            System.out.println(mobile);
            System.out.println(salary);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In Java, the == operator checks equality by reference. In this case, q and address won't match.  You want to use the "equals" method: address.equals(q).  Also consider converting the strings to upper or lowercase before comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You must compare strings using `equals()` method.

`==` tests for reference equality (whether they are the same object).

`.equals()` tests for value equality (whether they are logically "equal").

Variable `String address` and `String q = "Banglore"` are not the same objects, so `address == q` returns `false`.

Replace `if(address==q && salary>25000)` on `if(q.equals(address) && salary>25000)`, and it will work perfectly.

Comment: if i will create a object and this string value in that and then use that object with address using == will it work.

Comment: What object? An instance of Object class or what?

Comment: instance of class object ob

Comment: If `q` and `ob.address` have the same reference, `ob.address == q` returns `true`.

Comment: The easiest way to compare 2 strings is using the code like this `q.equals(address)`.

Comment: @hta72 don't *ever* compare the *content* of two strings with `==`: **always** use `equals`. Don't come with complicated "what if I do this" scenerio's - there is no reason ever to compare the *content* of strings with `==`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `if(address==q && salary>25000)` you can use `if (address.equals(q) && salary > 25000)` it should work then.

Comment: I've already written about that.